# Disabling PHP Magic Quotes To Remove Slash Caused By mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

I always got **\ (back slash)** from any variables which I put mysql_real_escape_string into. for example :

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['string']);
echo $string; //result : here\'s the text
```

and after I did some research on Google, some people says that this back-slash caused by server setting which has magic_quotes_gpc turned on. which I have this configuration too. I see it on my `phpinfo(), magic_quotes_gpc = ON`

my question is... Is it really safe to turn off this magic_quotes_gpc? 
Because I'm using mysql_real_escape_string to prevent mysql injection. by turning magic_quotes_gpc off, I'm afraid this will cause my server 'less powerful'.

Comment: What do you think `mysql_real_escape_string` does?

Comment: The backslash is there because you called `mysql_real_escape_string`. This has nothing at all to do with magic quotes, which would have added the backslash without you having called `mres`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: It seems that you do not understand what the code you have does. This means that you are almost certainly open to attacks (impossible to achieve security without understanding it first). Please take some time to read about SQL injection.

Comment: by the way, for questions like this, it would also help to tell us what version of PHP you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to have some fairly basic tuition on these subjects. You've clearly been reading up on the internet and following examples, but without actually understanding why the examples are doing what they're doing, or how they work. Copying examples without understanding them is not a good thing.

So at the core you need some deeper understanding of the topics, which is probably too much for a site like this to provide (SO is more about helping people solve specific problems than teaching them whole subjects, though you will learn a lot from browsing the site).

However, I will address some of your points:

- Magic Quotes is an obsolete PHP feature; in fact, it's been removed entirely from the most recent versions of PHP. Disabling it will **not** make your server "less powerful", or anything of the sort. In fact, it is recommended not to use it.
- All the functions beginning with `mysql_` have also been deprecated and are not recommended any more. The newer alternatives are the `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library. If you're following tutorials using the old functions, you should find a newer tutorial.
- The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function (and the mysqli/PDO equivalents) is intended to add a slash to your string where it finds quote characters or other characters that would cause a SQL statement to be invalid. Finding a slash in your string after running this function is perfectly normal and correct. This is called "escaping" the string (hence the name of the function). The "escaped" version of the string should only be used in the context of building a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your code takes care of properly escaping certain strings (like by calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` etc) you can disable this feature in php.ini. In fact you shall always ensure your running environment is set to parameters you need by either tuning `php.ini` or using `.htaccess` to set them up for particular vhost.

Relying on all these `magic_...` things is broken from the start because once it is turned off you basically got problem. Usually unnoticed, unless you get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're expecting `mysql_real_escape_string` to do?

It is escaping the string, so `here\'s the text` is the expected output. This is nothing to do with magic quotes, which would already have escaped the string, giving you `here\\'s the text` as the result after calling `mysql_real_escape_string`.

---

Of course, as was already mentioned in comments, you shouldn't be using the `MySQL_*` family of methods within PHP anymore as they are [deprecated](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Consider using `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead, along with prepared statements.